# GCP Console app for macos

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google

Does anyone know where I can find the Google Cloud Platform Console app for macos? I had it installed previously, but rebuild my machine and lost the installer. I have trouble running the Console in a browser (too many identities!)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Cloud SDK for MacOS over at [this link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos) along with a quickstart guide on how to install it and initialize it.

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it's not the SDK I was after, I already have that. It's an actual desktop macos app that has the same functionality as the web-based console.

Comment: I haven't heard of an App to use the GCP cosole from your desktop, the closest thing I know of is the [GCP app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/google-cloud-console/id1005120814), but to my knowledge these are maily for mobile